# node.js sequelize: multiple 'where' query conditions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do i query a table with multiple conditions?
Here are the examples both working:

```
Post.findAll({ where: ['deletedAt IS NULL'] }).success()
```

and

```
Post.findAll({ where: {topicId: req.params.id} }).success()
```

Then, if i need conditions combined, i feel like i need to do something like

```
Post.findAll({ where: [{topicId: req.params.id}, 'deletedAt IS NULL'] }).success()
```

, but it doesn't work.
What is the syntax the sequelize waits for?

node debug says:

> DEBUG: TypeError: Object # has no method 'replace'

if it matters...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please note that as of this posting and the 2015 version of sequelize, the above answers are out of date. I am posting the solution that I got working in hopes of saving someone some time.

```
filters["State"] = {$and: [filters["State"], {$not: this.filterSBM()}] };
```

Note the $ and array inside the JSON object and lack of ? token replacement.

Or put in a more general way, since that might help someone wrap their head around it:

```
{ $and: [{"Key1": "Value1"}, {"Key2": "Value2"}] }
```

Comment: Instead of mentioning `the most recent version of sequelize`, it would be useful if you quote the exact version. When I read your 2015 post in 2020, fairly sure the version you referenced is not `the most recent version` anymore.

Comment: Reasonable. I also wrote that off the cuff while on the job I had 5 years ago, but I'll bear that in mind.

Answer (score 29):

You can do:

```
Post.findAll({ where: {deletedAt: null, topicId: req.params.id} })
```

Which would be translated to `deletedAt IS NULL`

BTW, if you need `deletedAt NOT IS NULL`, use:

```
Post.findAll({ where: {deletedAt: {$ne: null}, topicId: req.params.id} })
```

Comment: Please update your answer to check multiple where, show are only showing one condition where as he needs to check number and null.

Answer (score 11):

Just do:

```
Post.findAll(
    { where: ["topicId = ? AND deletedAt IS NULL", req.params.id] }
).success()
```

Or do you need an or query?

Comment: Its AND that i needed, and your solution perfectly fits my needs, so thank you.

Comment: I must say its kinda obvious what u have done there, how could I not have done so myself?)  
But it feels more like workaround, I'm still curious what would I do if both conditions had parameters? Or if there'd be more conditions? Sequelize manuals doesn't have anything on such cases...

Comment: Nvm, i just found out that there can be several parameters provided subsequently for '?'s.
Thanks again)

Answer (score 7):

In **new version** try this

```
Post.findAll({
  where: {
    authorId: 12,
    status: 'active'
  }
}).then(function (data) {
    res.status(200).json(data)
            })
   .catch(function (error) {
                res.status(500).json(error)
   });;
```

Answer (score 7):

This gives me
`` SELECT `id`, `title`, `description`, `test`, `published`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `tests` AS `test` WHERE (`test`.`title` LIKE '%3%' OR `test`.`description` LIKE '%2%'); ``

```
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    const title = req.query.title;
    const description = req.query.description;
    Tutorial.findAll({
            where: {
                [Op.or]: [{
                        title: {
                            [Op.like]: `%${title}%`
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        description: {
                            [Op.like]: `%${description}%`
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials."
            });
        });

};
```

Comment: This is the right answer. For some reason, most of the people above provided answers for AND condition. This works in Sequelize 6.